# To prove that $a_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis

To prove that $a_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges

Now we have sequence $b_n= \frac{1}{n}$ converges.
For given $\epsilon > 0 $ , we have for $n \geq N_1 , |\frac{1}{n}| < \epsilon$

Now we consider two cases :

1. when n is even

so we have $a_n = b_n$ and hence converges to 0 , for even numbers bigger than $N_1$

2. when we have n as odd

then $a_n = \frac{-1}{n} $

as given we have for $n \geq N_1$, $\frac{1}{n}  \in (-\epsilon, +\epsilon ) $ which implies that $\frac{-1}{n} \in (-\epsilon, +\epsilon )$. so for odd numbers bigger than N_1  we have  a_n converges to 0

I am not sure about this proof

Comment: You are thinking too complicated. $|a_n - 0| = \frac 1n$ holds for *all* $n$.

Comment: This probably doesn't answer your question but you can use the alternating series test, which says it converges as 1) $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ and 2) $|a_{n+1}| \le |a_n|$ for all $n$.

Comment: @TobyMak yeah i havenot reached this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the definition, a sequence ${a_n}$ is said to converge to a limit $L$ equivalent to

$\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists N>0\quad\forall n>N \quad s.t.\quad |a_n-L|<\epsilon $

So your proof can be written just like this

$\forall \epsilon>0\quad \exists N=[\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}]+1\quad \forall n>N\quad s.t. \quad|a_n-0|=|\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}|<|\dfrac{1}{N}|<\epsilon $

So by the above definition we immediately get that the limit of $a_n$ is $0$.

However, your proof is also correct that it is also common to treat odd and even terms separately.

Comment: what is that notationyou used with 1\epsilon

Comment: This notation means rounding down, i.e. [x] is the largest integer that does not exceed x.

Comment: why not just say N > 1\epsilon ?

Comment: Of course you can do this, but considering that n is an integer greater than 0 and N is a lower bound on n, it is customary to take it as an integer as well.